# ASP.NET MVC - weird style being generated in release mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles/Default").Include("~/Content/Styles/Default/Site.css"));
```

On my sites i have this:

```
@section Styles
{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles/Default"))
}
```

My _Layout.cshtml looks like this:

```
@RenderSection("Styles", true)
```

Everything looks good, eh? Well, not really. When i compiled my application in release mode, decided to publish it, this is what it renders:

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/Default?v=78dkNySP_xsiuzsgxCx_GGnnHzYS-B8nNdnXqcl47XI1" rel="stylesheet">
```

Instead of generating href to a file, it generates some kind of id? Guid? Why? O.o

Comment: Probably so that browsers will get the latest version and not hang on to a cached one.

Comment: This is how `Styles.Render` works in release mode... I highly recommend that you read about he feature what you are trying to use [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: But my browser cannot read that! There is no physical path to a file!

Answer (score 3):

This is how bundles work. It's main purpose is for you to combine multiple CSS (and JS files for that matter) files into one package. e.g. you no longer have to put all your css (and js) into one huge file. Just split it up into sections, then add it into your bundles, and it packages it up into one item. Less web requests, the faster your page load time.

e.g. Lets say you had 2 css files. One's the main, but you had one for your menu system.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles/Default").Include(
        "~/Content/Styles/Default/Site.css",
        "~/Content/Styles/Default/Menu.css"));
```

This would show up as a single call with the GUID type code (to prevent caching on file changes) on the URL. This URL will link to a minified and bundled css.

> But my browser cannot read that! There is no physical path to a file!

It's a sort of virtual file. MVC's bundling uses the routing engine to point it to a combined and minified version of a particle bundle.